# Passing a character-element to render() to create several different PDFs

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I try to create a number of PDFs with Markdown which all look the same, but use different data. For this purpose I created a little bit of code to generate random data which should be used in the creation of the PDF-File.

```
library(tidyverse) 


r_sample <- seq(1, 5, by = 0.1)

nr_rows <- 10

df_names <- vector()

for(i in 1:2){
  name <- paste0("i_",i)
  
  i_sample <- tibble("Name" = paste0("i_", seq(1:nr_rows)))
  i_sample <- i_sample %>% add_column(sample(r_sample, nr_rows, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
    rename("Value" = "sample(r_sample, nr_rows, replace = TRUE)")
  
  
  assign(name, i_sample)
  df_names[i] <- name
}
```

The Markdown-Script is almost empty, since it is just used for testing purposes.

````
---
title: "Test"
output: pdf_document
params: 
  data : ""
---

This is just a Test. 

```{r echo = FALSE}

params$data
```.  #error made intentionally!
````

Now I try to get the data from my R-Script into the Markdown-Script using `render()`. Since I want to loop over the different dataframes, I wrote a simple loop.

```
for(i in 1:2){
  rmarkdown::render('Test.Rmd', params = list(data = df_names[i]), 
                    output_file = glue::glue(paste0("file_", df_names[i], ".pdf")))
}
```

Now to the problem. Markdown understands the input of `env_names[i]` as a character and not as the dataframe. However if I type it manually like this:

```
rmarkdown::render('Test.Rmd', params = list(data = i_1), output_file = glue::glue(paste0("file_i_1.pdf")))
```

it works. I understand the problem, but I can't find a way to work around this.

If anyone could help I would be very glad! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO, @L.Gottwald! There are several aspects of this question that confuse me. 1) In the first snippet, the `name` variable and the use of `assign` seem overly complex - and unecessary, given that `df_names[i] <- i_sample` should do the same (?). 2) Why the "intentional error" in the Rmarkdown script? 3) What is `env_names`? Did you mean `df_names`? 4) I don't know `glue` but I'm almost certain you don't need it.

Comment: Hey @CL. thanks for the answer. To your questions.
1) I want to create different data_frames therefore the assign. I'm not sure, if it works your way. 
2) I put the dot at the and (the error) so that the three ` get displayed. Otherwise the code chunk would have ended. 
3) That was a typo. It should be `df_names` in this example. I changed it in my script while writing this post. 
4) I don't know `glue` either, got this example from SO as well and hoped to get it working. 

Does this help a little?

Comment: 1) Now I see what you're doing there. Yes, this is different than what I proposed. However, I think instead of dynamically creating variables, the more idomatic way would be to use a list. 2) I still don't understand this one. Why do you want to see the 3 backticks? Isn't the expected output just the contents of `params$data`? 3) You can [edit] the question to make the naming consistent.

Comment: Ok, assuming that you just want to print `params$data`, the direct solution should be to use `get(df_names[i])` instead of `df_names[i]` in the call to `rmarkdown::render`. Let me know if this helps - if yes, then I can draft a more verbose answer with some more potential improvements.

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much! I tried a lot of things to work around the character problem but never tried `get`. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direct fix for the problem at hand is to wrap `df_names[i]` in `get()` in order to access the object whose name matches `df_names[i]` instead of passing the value of `df_names[i]` to `render()`:

```
rmarkdown::render('Test.Rmd', params = list(data = get(df_names[i])), 
                    output_file = glue::glue(paste0("file_", df_names[i], ".pdf")))
```

Yet, dynamically creating objects using `assign` in the global environment is rather unidiomatic in R – and not doing this also eradicates the need for using `get()` afterwards.

Therefore, I propose to write the code snippet from the question as follows:

```
r_sample <- seq(1, 5, by = 0.1)
nr_rows <- 10

df_list <- list()

for(i in 1:2){
  df_list[[i]] <- tibble(Name = paste0("i_", seq(1:nr_rows)), Value = sample(r_sample, nr_rows, replace = TRUE))
}
```

Then, the loop render the documents becomes:

```
for(i in 1:2){
  rmarkdown::render('Test.Rmd', params = list(data = df_list[[i]]), 
                    output_file = paste0("file_i_", i, ".pdf"))
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm am not used to work with lists. Every time I have to work with bigger data I use tibble. Lists never come to my mind even though it would be simpler.